# Cross entropy yields different results for vectors with identical distributions

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

I am training a neural network to distinguish between three classes. Naturally, I went for PyTorch's `CrossEntropyLoss`. During experimentation, I realized that the loss was significantly higher when a `Softmax` layer was put at the end of the model. So I decided to experiment further:

```
import torch
from torch import nn

pred_1 = torch.Tensor([[0.1, 0.2, 0.7]])
pred_2 = torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 7]])
pred_3 = torch.Tensor([[2, 4, 14]])
true = torch.Tensor([2]).long()

loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

print(loss(pred_1, true))
print(loss(pred_2, true))
print(loss(pred_3, true))
```

The result of this code is as follows:

```
0.7679
0.0092
5.1497e-05
```

I also tried what happens when multiplying the input with some constant.
[image: losses for different multipliers]

Several sources ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030217/shall-i-apply-softmax-before-cross-entropy), [2](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/vgg-output-layer-no-softmax/9273/2)) stated that the loss has a softmax built in, but if that were the case, I would have expected all of the examples above to return the same loss, which clearly isn't the case.

This poses the following question: if bigger outputs lead to a lower loss, wouldn't the network optimize towards outputting bigger values, thereby skewing the loss curves? If so, it seems like a `Softmax` layer would fix that. But since this results in a higher loss overall, how useful would the resulting loss actually be?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html), the input to `CrossEntropyLoss` "is expected to contain raw, unnormalized scores for each class". Those are typically called [logits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit).

There are two questions:

- Scaling the logits should *not* yield the same cross-entropy. You might be thinking of a linear normalization, but the (implicit) softmax in the cross-entropy normalizes [the exponential of the logits](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softmax.html).
- This causes the learning to optimize toward larger values of the logits. This is *exactly what you want* because it means that the network is more "confident" of the classification prediction. (The posterior p(c|x) is closer to the ground truth.)

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. However, could it in theory be possible for the network to just keep producing larger and larger outputs, thereby reducing the loss? I reccon that in practice this will never be the case due to a variety of reasons. But it seems a bit odd to me that simply raising all output nodes results in a lower loss.

Comment: It is totally possible, and not just in theory... This is usually not a problem because (1) the loss saturates and thus the "incentive" (i.e., gradient) converges to zero, and (2) one should stop training early (a.k.a., early-stopping) based on the validation loss. Moreover, one typically adds regularization on the layer weights which translates on a loss term pulling in the opposite direction (and which stabilizes it thanks to (1)).